# How can I prevent last flex item from overflowing parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to make the last flex item in my list not expand past the bottom of the container.  It has a contenteditable div in it that I need to expand up when someone enters more than one line of text.

The main flex items are 3 divs in a column, the title bar is 100% width, the content container is 100% width with grow and shrink and the footer is flex and should cause the inner container to shrink.

Currently when you enter more than one line of text in div.detail-chat-input it does expand upwards, but it also pushes the buttons down.

Like this:

[image: Footer buttons overflowing the container]

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-popover-window {
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel-popover-title-bar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.panel-popover-column-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.panel-popover-panel {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel-popover-panel-title {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-footer {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.panel-popover-footer-content {
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-footer-button-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.panel-popover-close-button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 83px;
  height: 37px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.detail-chat-input {
  min-height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.detail-activity-scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.detail-message-container {
  min-height: 800px;
}

.panel-popover-panel.activity {
  max-height: 685px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel-popover-window detail-popover" style="width: 1200px; height: 875px;">
      <div class="panel-popover-title-bar">
        <span class="panel-popover-title-bar-text">Popover Title</span>
        <div class="panel-popover-title-bar-close"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-popover-content">
        <div class="panel-popover-column panel-popover-column-2">
          <div class="panel-popover-panel submission-info">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 1</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-popover-panel statistics">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 2</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-popover-column panel-popover-column-2">
          <div class="panel-popover-panel activity">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 3</div>
            <div class="detail-activity-scrollable">
              <div class="detail-message-container">
                  <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-popover-footer">
        <div class="panel-popover-footer-content">
          <textarea class="detail-chat-input" placeholder="Send Message" data-emojiable="converted" style="display: none;" data-id="8ff80f0d-85e3-4ac4-acbf-c950fffbc1a4" data-type="original-input"></textarea>
          <div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor detail-chat-input parent-has-scroll" placeholder="Send Message" contenteditable="true"></div>
          <div class="panel-popover-footer-button-bar">
            <button class="detail-admin-control detail-approve" disabled="">Button 1</button>
            <button class="detail-admin-control detail-disapprove">Button 2</button>
            <div class="panel-popover-close-button">Close</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to give max-height and overflow to chat div which is editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a `height: 100%;` to the `.panel-popover-window` container.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel-popover-window {
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 1200px; 
  height: 100%;
}

.panel-popover-title-bar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.panel-popover-column-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.panel-popover-panel {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel-popover-panel-title {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-footer {
  min-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.panel-popover-footer-content {
  position: relative;
}

.panel-popover-footer-button-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.panel-popover-close-button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 83px;
  height: 37px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.detail-chat-input {
  min-height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.detail-activity-scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.detail-message-container {
  min-height: 800px;
}

.panel-popover-panel.activity {
  max-height: 685px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="panel-popover-window detail-popover">
      <div class="panel-popover-title-bar">
        <span class="panel-popover-title-bar-text">Popover Title</span>
        <div class="panel-popover-title-bar-close"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-popover-content">
        <div class="panel-popover-column panel-popover-column-2">
          <div class="panel-popover-panel submission-info">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 1</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-popover-panel statistics">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 2</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
            <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-popover-column panel-popover-column-2">
          <div class="panel-popover-panel activity">
            <div class="panel-popover-panel-title">Title 3</div>
            <div class="detail-activity-scrollable">
              <div class="detail-message-container">
                  <div class="ad-approval-panel-line">Data</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-popover-footer">
        <div class="panel-popover-footer-content">
          <textarea class="detail-chat-input" placeholder="Send Message" data-emojiable="converted" style="display: none;" data-id="8ff80f0d-85e3-4ac4-acbf-c950fffbc1a4" data-type="original-input"></textarea>
          <div class="emoji-wysiwyg-editor detail-chat-input parent-has-scroll" placeholder="Send Message" contenteditable="true"></div>
          <div class="panel-popover-footer-button-bar">
            <button class="detail-admin-control detail-approve" disabled="">Button 1</button>
            <button class="detail-admin-control detail-disapprove">Button 2</button>
            <div class="panel-popover-close-button">Close</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this snippet is still pushing the buttons below the content editable div down off the end of the container with enough new lines in the chat div.

Comment: But its not flowing out of grey background. If you want to stop that as well. Reduce the max-height. Or better git it a height.

Comment: Edit - Or better `give` it a height.

Comment: I want it to grow, setting a height will stop it from growing.  I'm trying to create a chat input that works like slack or skype when you enter multiple lines of text.

Comment: Run my code now. I hope the buttons are not flowing out as you wanted.